# HTTP/2 Image load times - waiting for the last one to finish

Tags: asp.net, image, performance, iis, http2

This is baffling me. On a new server (Windows Server 2016) my images seem to be loading in synchronously. The browser is attempting to download them all at the same time, but something is stopping the image from loading until the previous one has finished. The time to first byte increases as each image is attempted to be loaded.

EDIT: I have posted my imagehandler code below, but you can see the problem exists when loading .jpg in its native format (see screenshot about half way down).

EDIT 2: I have disabled http/2 and added a screenshot.

[image]

My SVG image handler code (problem exists with image.ashx also):

```
    Dim freshness As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(now.Add(freshness))
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(freshness)
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)
    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(True)

    Response.Cache.VaryByParams("colour") = True
    Response.Cache.VaryByParams("colour2") = True
    Response.Cache.VaryByParams("svg") = True
    Response.Cache.VaryByParams("rnd") = True
    Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders("rnd") = True
    Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders("Type") = True


    Dim sSVG As String = Request.QueryString("svg").Split("-")(0)
    If sSVG = String.Empty Then
        Try
            sSVG = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME").Split("-")(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            sSVG = "svg"
        End Try
    End If


    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("\images\icons\svg\" & sSVG & ".svg"))

    Dim sColour As String = "FFFFFF"
    Dim sColour2 As String = "FFFFFF"
    Dim sXML As String = xDoc.Document.ToString
    If Request.QueryString("Colour") <> String.Empty Then
        sColour = Request.QueryString("Colour")
    Else
        Try
            sColour = sSVG.Split("-")(1)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
    If Request.QueryString("Colour2") <> String.Empty Then
        sColour2 = Request.QueryString("Colour2")
    Else
        Try
            sColour = sSVG.Split("-")(2)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If

    sXML = sXML.Replace("COLOUR2", sColour2)
    sXML = sXML.Replace("COLOUR", sColour)

    Response.Headers.Add("Vary", "Accept-Encoding")
    Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml"
    Response.Write(sXML)
```

HTTP/2 disabled:

[image]

Comment: Merely watching the browser side logging offers limited insight. There are IIS level failed request tracing and ASP.NET level ETW tracing you should enable and dig into.

Comment: All the browsers have restriction of concurrent request limit. [More Details](https://medium.com/@jperasmus11/domain-sharding-on-the-modern-web-dc97df4f6a90) This is the reason your request is getting queued.

Comment: शेखर no that is a restriction of HTTP/1. This is HTTP/2.